# C# adding an array to a ListView based on the index of another ListView

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listview

I have two ListView and a array of strings:

```
    string[] groceries = { "Bread", "Milk", "Cheese", "Fruit" };
```

When I select an index on the first ListView I want the second ListView to repopulate itself with the groceries in the array.

If you don't understand what I'm trying to get at, take a look here:

- when user selects index 0 in listView1
- get the array values (which are bread, milk, cheese and fruit)
- add them to listView2

Comment: Looks like you are trying to populate a listview based on an event? WPF or windows forms? It's not completely clear what you are asking. :)

Comment: You haven't specified your question very clearly, please improve it by editing your post

Comment: @jsmith Windows Forms as I don't use XML to define the appearance. And yes, I want to populate a listView2 with the items on an array when a certain index on listView1 is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudocode is alright... seems like you know what you have to do. See if this helps, or at least steers you in the right direction.

When the selected index changes in the first `ListView`:

- see if the selected index is `0` (assuming that's the one you want to test for),
- then clear the items in the second `ListView` and add your grocery items.

---

```
void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Contains(0))
    {
        listView2.Items.Clear();
        listView2.Items.AddRange(groceries.Select(g => new ListViewItem(g)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I realize this doesn't answer the question now that you have clarified it, but I had started coming up with the response based on a WPF implementation. I'm proud of it so I'm going to post it and maybe it will help someone else.

The sample code below will change the content of one list view based on the selected index of another list view.

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewArrays.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:listViewArrays="clr-namespace:ListViewArrays"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <listViewArrays:ListViewModel x:Key="testData" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testData}, Path=OriginalList}" 
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource testData}, Path=OriginalListSelectedIndex}" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testData}, Path=DependentList}"/>
</Grid>
```

With the ViewModel defined below:

```
    public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _originalList = new[] {"Groceries", "Test"};
    private IEnumerable<string> _dependentList;
    private int _originalListSelectedIndex;

    public IEnumerable<string> OriginalList
    {
        get { return _originalList; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> DependentList
    {
        get { return _dependentList; }
        set
        {
            _dependentList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int OriginalListSelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _originalListSelectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _originalListSelectedIndex = value;
            //Logic for changing dependent list goes here
            if (_originalListSelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                DependentList = new[] { "Bread", "Milk", "Cheese", "Fruit" };
            }
            else
            {
                DependentList = new[] { "test 1", "test 2" };
            }
        }
    }

}
```